Missing Docker container logs?
Docker typically stores its logs in
/var/lib/docker/containers

On my system, this directory is empty.
If I open the Docker Desktop GUI and look at the Inspect tab for a container, I can see an entry for LogPath.
However, that directory does not appear to exist on my system. Why is this?

Run docker info: that result will show where your daemon directory is, or you can change your root data if this is not a production server, then find your data root.
I suggest double checking there, and if you don't found anything you can manually edit your docker logging by editing /etc/docker/daemon.json or systemctl edit docker check the following link:

I think you forgot to include the link.

where's the link, lol
